# MySQL: VARCHAR(1024) vs VARCHAR(512)

Tags: mysql

In MySQL what is the difference between `VARCHAR(1024)` and `VARCHAR(512)`? If my item will never be more than 512 characters, what do I lose by using `VARCHAR(1024)`?

Comment: There's no `VARCHAR` type in MySQL. There's only `VARCHAR(N)` type. For `MySQL<5.0.3` it's `N<255` and for later versions `N<65535`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know where you got that from, but it's not possible to create a table with varchar without specifying the length. It results in a syntax error. So your question is obsolete.

UPDATE:

Nothing. Varchar is as the name implies a datatype of variable length, at least to the maximum length you specified when creating the table. This means, that in a varchar column for each row one additional byte is used to store how long the string in the row actually is. 
So the difference between varchar(1024) and varchar(512) is, that your data gets truncated when you try to insert more than 1024 or 512 bytes. Note: bytes, not characters. How much bytes each character uses is dependent on the character set you're using.

Comment: CHAR and VARCHAR specifies the field length in characters, not bytes. In  MySQL 1 character can take from 1 (eg. latin1) to 4 (utf8mb4, utf32) bytes depending on the encoding.

Answer (score 3):

There is a actually a difference. And it can have a big performance impact if you manipulate big data. If a temporary table is used, the records on disk will take the full length indicated instead of the variable length. A high value will slow down the request even more in that case. Temporary tables can occur for various reasons (such as memory full, or some combinations of group by /order by).

Comment: And **what** is that difference? How is that related to a temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR(1024) 1024 this is lenght.

The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, CHAR(30) can hold up to 30 characters.

Comment: This question is some years old, and already holds some answers. It's okay to add a new one, but it should also add some new insights and not only duplicate the existing answers

Comment: This question has wrong answer. I has not duplicated the existing answer.

Comment: If you think that the existing answer is wrong, please expand your answer to contain all neccessary information.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)

> In contrast to CHAR, VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte
> length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of
> bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no
> more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than
> 255 bytes.

A deeper analysis of the performance impact of larger VARCHARs can be found [here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/mysql-varchar-length-and-performance)